# Is there a solution to auto-post data to a WP post from a database

Tags: database, automation

I'm looking to add posts to my WP website from a (self managed) database source - could be form or excel/CSV data, either internally (in WP itself) or external, i.e. from an excel sheet in Dropbox.
I have a lot of data to upload and doing this in each post is very time consuming. If I could add it to a form or excel sheet and that would push to a WP database/post it would dramatically reduce my production time. Even possibly have a (hidden) WP page with a form in it linking to the WP database.

Comment: I think you are looking for this plugin - Import any XML or CSV File to WordPress
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Comment: sort of - this is an upload solution. I dont want to have to upload a file each time it is edited... it should sync with the WP database.

Comment: What would you consider a "solution" ? Are you interested in developing this? Finding a ready-made plugin? Please note that asking for plugin recommendations is considered not in scope here.

Comment: I'm not a developer looking to develop this. I have a requirement and I'm looking to see if there is a solution to it. The process of adding a WP Post is tedious with many of them, so adding it to a centralized spreadsheet and have that sync with the WP database would be a great solution but not sure something like this exists - I've looked everywhere